# Google Cloud Run only has access to subset of metadata on http://metadata.google.internal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

### Problem: Google Cloud Run only provides a subset of documented metadata

I have a simple JVM based application running on Google Cloud Run that queries `http://metadata.google.internal` for available metadata.

The only metadata available is at the following paths:

- `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts`
- `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone`
- `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id`
- `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/numeric-project-id`

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#default), I was expecting more than this and hoping that I would be able to query the metadata server for the name of the Cloud Run service and the [metadata required](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_generic_node) to configure Stackdriver Monitoring for a `generic_node`.

One clue that I have found is in the `server` header in the response from querying the Metadata server gives the value: `Metadata Server for Serverless`

**Theory:** Cloud Run is in beta and the `Metadata Server for Serverless` is separate from the typical metadata server and is a work in progress.

**Question(s):**

1. Is this theory valid?
2. Is this limitation documented somewhere?

   - Is there a roadmap for adding additional metadata?
3. Is there an alternative for determining the metadata needed to configure Stackdriver?

Comment: Instead of asking why is Cloud Run metadata different from Compute Engine, can you specify what you need?

Comment: Your theory is no really valid. Cloud Run is GA! However, maybe that Medata Server for Serverless is in Beta

Comment: There is some documentation about metadata specifically for Cloud Run here: The metadata available to a Google Cloud Run container is documented here now: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#metadata-server.

But it also is rather vague and does not specify which metadata endpoints are available and which are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Compute Metadata service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#default) you linked is only available to Compute Engine products (such as GCE, GKE). Many of the endpoints in there are about VM details, VM metadata/tags, VM startup scripts etc.

These concepts don't apply to serverless compute environments. Therefore I don't think a feature request here will succeed.

Serverless products such as App Engine, Cloud Functions and Cloud Run support a minimal version of the metadata service to provide basic functionality to SDKs (such as Google Cloud client libraries, Stackdriver or OpenTelemetry/OpenCensus clients, or `gcloud` CLI). Using these endpoints, Google’s own client libraries can automatically get auth tokens, discover project IDs etc.

Also, these serverless products don't run on GCE, and don't have the same concepts. That's why a full metadata service isn't available for these products.

The applicable for serverless environments are the endpoints you listed in your question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and that's kind of what I suspected. I agree with your point that not all compute engine metadata applies to serverless compute environments but at the same time I can't find an explicit part of the Cloud Run docs to say *The metadata server is different*. The docs even link to the compute metadata which adds to the confusion. If there was some documentation for the Metadata Server for Serverless I think that would be tremendously helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will find much information in order to validate your theory as that has to do with the product's architecture and I don't think Google will share it for the moment, however, it does seem to be valid based on the evidence you found.

What can be done is to open a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to Google so that they work on adding more information to the metadata so that it cover your needs. As the product is on beta, they should be open to do some changes.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've raised a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148523767 I will update here as and when I get any feedback