# Return active GCP project name programatically for both local dev and deployed Cloud Run projects

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am working on code that will leverage GCP's CI/CD build > deploy. Part of that process is staging it as a test deploy and running integration tests in a non-production project. That code will ultimately be promoted to a production project.

As a result, I would like to be able to dynamically adjust which project the deployed code is running under.

Is there a way to get the current environment's active project name in python like you can with `gccloud config get-value project`?

I would like to work in my local development environment **and** in deployments on Cloud Run.

Most of the answers I've found are only for deployments, and because of that I can't test locally.

This code kind of works, but I would prefer to use the GCP SDK and not resort to executing a subprocess.

```js
try:
    project_id = os.system('gcloud %s %s %s' %("config", "get-value", "project")).read()
    print(project_id)
    pass
except:
    print("Error running command")
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI configuration information is stored in a file. The format is INI. For Python use the `configparser` package.

Windows:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\configurations\config_default
```

Linux:

```
~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default
```

Comment: Does this hold true for Cloud Run deployed containers? Or would I need to install gcloud as part of the deployment?

Comment: @Dshiz - Yes, if you have installed and configured the CLI in the container before deploying to Cloud Run otherwise the file will not exist. The CLI config options are set by the user, there is no CLI default project until set manually. In Cloud Run, you can read the Cloud Run Project ID from the Metadata service, which is the correct method. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59954901/8016720

Comment: I just noticed that it is not does not have the actual GCP project name.. I'm not sure what entities' name it is returning, but it is similar to the name of my application.

Comment: I think I know what this is. I was signed into my personal GCP account before signing into my work one. For some reason `default_config` never updated. I'll simply modify it manually. Which may fix another issue I have pulling images to my local kubernetes engine